# View entire activities of an user in github

Tags: git, github

How can I view the entire activities of an user in github.com .

Say Mr.Geos entire activites

- Mr.Geo pushed to ..
- Mr.Geo deleted ...
- ...

Comment: If you tried doing that through the API, this might be programming related.

Comment: @Abhi - Just to to https://github.com/username/ and look on the right side. Everything related to user's public repositories will be there ...

Comment: @vpatil This is not a duplicate. This is related to online activities on the GitHub website and goes beyond the commit log of a sole repository.

Comment: @vpatil: not a dupe, this question relates to all github activity, the question you linked relates to a git repository activity

Comment: You can use Github-events-viewer for your own user:  https://rawgit.com/zbycz/github-events-viewer/master/github-event-viewer.html

Comment: As far as I'm concerned zbycz's comment is an answer and the best one (most everything else (if not all of it) points to useless _computer-friendly_, not _user-friendly_--output.

Answer (score 53):

You can leverage the **GitHub Events API** to perform such task and retrieve a JSON formatted response.

> The [Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) is a read-only interface to all the [event types](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/) that
>   power the various activity streams on GitHub.

- **syntax:** `GET /users/:user/events`
- **example:** https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events

An alternative way is to subscribe to the public RSS feed of a user. 
For instance, **[Mojombo](https://github.com/mojombo)**'s public feed Url would be

- https://github.com/mojombo.atom

Also If you want to view Full activities performed by all contributors ,you can also go to

If Private
https://github.com/orgs/YOURORGANISATION/dashboard

If Public
https://github.com/REPOSITORYOWNER?tab=activity

Comment: These only seem to provide the same truncated list as https://github.com/motumbo?tab=activity

Comment: Tack on `?page=2` etc.

Comment: @u01jmg3, your comment should be the answer `?tab=activity&page=2`, too bad it's closed!

Comment: I just searched back a few pages and it doesn't seem to store all history.  Mine only went back a few months - though I assume it's relative to number of items as opposed to amount of time.

Comment: A potential alternative would be to query https://www.githubarchive.org/ data which stores all public github events from 2011-12-02

Comment: Only owner of the org can see this report: https://github.com/orgs/YOURORGANISATION/dashboard. As a site admin, I just added myself as an owner of this org, but see nothing for this org. Guess it's only display since I become an owner? Is there a way to list everything since Jan 2016?

Comment: @nulltoken I think https://githubcontributions.io/user/mr-geo/events/1 is quite nice, too

Comment: Unfortunately, the `?tab=activity` is gone since a few days, it there a replacement? I used this link every day, and now I cannot find my own comments on github any more. Is there another page for the activity now? (apart from the .atom feed)?

Comment: @rubo77 this appears due to the new GitHub design. You'll need to use the atom link

Comment: The site https://opensourcecontributo.rs/user/<username>/events/1 works fine but is not up-to-date, the last few minutes are not on the list. If that's enough for you it is the best option. but if you want to see the latest activity, you need the atom feed: https://github.com/<username>.atom which shows everything in firefox (for chrome, you need an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-feed-reader/))

Comment: This is subject to the constraints mentioned however (last 300 events or last 90 days, whichever is less)

Comment: Is it possible to view user's (my) thumbs_ups, hearts and other comment like-actions?

Comment: @Qwerty That would make a perfect SO question of its own! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the /dashboards  link.