# Activity tab for GitHub

Tags: git, github, gitlab, collaboration

GitLab has an Activity tab where I can see all activity for all branches for a given project.

[image]

I working on a personal project where I have a couple team mates. I'd like to see all activity for the project in a similar way on GitHub. Is this possible?

I found this: [View entire activities of an user in github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128049/view-entire-activities-of-an-user-in-github)

But the GitHub events link provided ([here](https://developer.github.com/v3/events/)) is broken. They also suggest subscribing to a public RSS feed. But I was looking for an integrated option to view all activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you're part of an organization, you can see the activity in the dashboard:

```
https://github.com/orgs/<your-organization>/dashboard
```

If you just have a repository with collaborators, you can <kbd>Watch</kbd> the repository (you are most probably already watching it) and you will get the notifications in your dashboard:

```
https://github.com/
```

To get repository level activity only, you can use the API. The [GitHub API Events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) may help you.

For example, to get [`git-stats`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats)'s activity, you have to access this url:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/IonicaBizau/git-stats/events
```

Using [`gh.js`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/gh.js) you can get the responses in your Node.js / JavaScript application:

```
var GitHub = require("gh.js");

var gh = new GitHub({
    token: "an optional token"
});

gh.get("repos/IonicaBizau/git-stats", function (err, events) {
    console.log(err || events);
});
```