# Get a list of all your activities on GitHub

Tags: github, github-api

On my GitHub account, I have public and private repositories and push rights to one or two external repositories. Is there a sensible way to get all my activities in chronological order? It should not only cover commits but also things like issues, comments, pushes, etc.

I know that basically, the GitHub API would provide such information but I'm not sure if it is possible to get all things at once and maybe there is already a tool for it.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128049/view-entire-activities-of-an-user-in-github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View entire activities of an user in github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128049/view-entire-activities-of-an-user-in-github)